# How to validate token generated by Auth0 in keycloak

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I have configured a client named "register" inside realm "master" and now trying to import the jws provided by auth0
clients->keys ->import -> provided the json web key set downloaded from auth0.

I've generated the token using

```
curl --location 'https://dev-6raffvdrfo14pj0h.us.auth0.com/oauth/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Cookie: did=s%3Av0%3A084cdd20-b699-11ed-ab7c-c1023b09e677.9GOrnBhLR4LKzjApyXf5acEU6jxoyj4IcvunT1dH4yU; did_compat=s%3Av0%3A084cdd20-b699-11ed-ab7c-c1023b09e677.9GOrnBhLR4LKzjApyXf5acEU6jxoyj4IcvunT1dH4yU' \
--data '{
    "client_id": "sMDsowt2nx2zyTGLDOos39xejoljTHIE",
    "client_secret": "1f5CY97KpYg5hgsPIEXdHMnEjZG5F_uWdtNaPUeyk7Ov8UClHFKZyDfD06NHgR50",
    "audience": "https://dev-6raffvdrfo14pj0h.us.auth0.com/api/v2/",
    "grant_type": "client_credentials"
}'
```

Once the token is generated by auth0 now trying to validate that token using introspect Api of key cloak

```
curl --location 'http://localhost:8080/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=tokenValidXYZ' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=JdVsJNWAvoJ4bdL5z7zP8zzGePWJPXYZ'
```

It's always returning false.

Logs:

> 2023-03-17 10:24:00,389 TRACE
> [org.keycloak.services.clientpolicy.DefaultClientPolicyManager]
> (executor-thread-0) POLICY OPERATION :: No enabled policy. 2023-03-17
> 10:24:00,454 TRACE [org.keycloak.keys.DefaultKeyManager]
> (executor-thread-0) Failed to find public key: realm=master
> kid=T1vLicgMxSzPE3KbhuUTn algorithm=RS256 use=SIG 2023-03-17
> 10:24:00,454 DEBUG
> [org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.AccessTokenIntrospectionProvider]
> (executor-thread-0) JWT check failed: Key not found

Comment: So you are sending a JWT from Auth0 to Keycloak for validation? This sounds like a misunderstanding of concepts. Your applications typically works with a single IdP only. If it is Keycloak and you want to accept Auth0 users as well, then add Auth0 as an IdP to Keycloak. Then Keycloak will issue an own JWT for Auth0 issuers and it will also validate them. If this doesn't answer your question, then please describe the full setup first: what are the involved IT systems, which users exist in which systems, what is their role in the setup etc.

Comment: @Codo Thanks for your response. I have updated the question with more details and logs.

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you are trying. But most likely you have misunderstood how federation works. The Keycloak introspect endpoint will never validate a Auth0 token, not matter the configuration. In federation, your web application redirects an unauthenticated user to Keycloak. If the user chooses to login with Auth0, he/she is redirected to Auth0. The Auth0 token is returned to Keycloak. Keycloak validates it and issues a new token for your web application. Your web application will only deal with Keycloak tokens.

Comment: You haven't provided any explanation of your setup. It might not even involve a web application, but just a backend service in the role of a resource server. If so, I don't understand why the role of Keycloak is. Why don't you call the introspect endpoint of Auth0?